# Combine two classes into common base class (template? mixin?)

Tags: c++, templates, mixins

We use a 3rd party library to control a specialized PCI card. The vendor released a new card which uses a new class to control it but the new class has the same methods as the old one.

If writing myself, I'd make a base class so we can have one set of code using a base class pointer to the derived object but we can't with this third party library.

I think this is a case for a *mixin* but I'm not sure.  The code below shows the situation.

Redefining each method in the template class is possible, but there are a lot of methods in `APIClass1` and `APIClass2`.  (the methods have the same name and signature).  I mean something like: `void one() { TBase::one(); }`

Is there a way in C++ to do this without duplicating a lot of code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class APIClass1
{
public:
    void one() { printf("APIClass1 ONE\n"); }
    void two() { printf("APIClass1 TWO\n"); }
};

class APIClass2
{
public:
    void one() { printf("APIClass2 ONE\n"); }
    void two() { printf("APIClass2 TWO\n"); }
};

class MasterClassBC
{ };

template <class T>
class MasterClass : public T, public MasterClassBC
{
public:
    typedef T TBase;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Use pointer to base class object
    MasterClassBC *pBc;
    if (isNewCard())
        pBc = new MasterClass<APIClass2>;
    else
        pBc = new MasterClass<APIClass1>;

    pBc->two(); // error:‘class MasterClassBC’ has no member named ‘two’
}
```

**EDIT I**

From StoryTeller's suggestion, I've got it almost working by putting pure virtual functions in the base class.  The new problem is that some functions have different signatures between `APIClass1` and `APIClass2`.

In the example below we have `void three()` and `void three(int n)`.

I tried creating `newThree()` which calls the appropriate function at run time but it doesn't compile since TBase is missing one or the other `three` methods depending how it was specialized.

```
class APIClass1
{
public:
    void one() { printf("APIClass1 ONE\n"); }
    void two() { printf("APIClass1 TWO\n"); }
    void three() { printf("APIClass1 THREE\n"); }
};

class APIClass2
{
public:
    void one() { printf("APIClass2 ONE\n"); }
    void two() { printf("APIClass2 TWO\n"); }
    void three(int n) { printf("APIClass2 THREE: %d\n", n); }
};

class MasterClassBC
{
    virtual void one() = 0;
    virtual void two() = 0;
    virtual void newThree() = 0
};

template <class T>
class MasterClass : public T, public MasterClassBC
{
public:
    typedef T TBase;
    MasterClass(bool useApi1 = true) : mUseApi1(useApi1) {}

    void setTheNumber(int n) { mTheNumber = n; }

    void one() { TBase::one(); }
    void two() { TBase::two(); }

    void newThree()
    {
        if (mUseApi1)
            TBase::three();
        else
            TBase::three(mTheNumber);
    }

private:
    bool mUseApi1;
    int  mTheNumber;
};
```

Comment: The [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is a handy pattern for the implementation of mixins.

Comment: You are almost there. But `MasterClassBC` won't magically obtain an interface unless you specify it explicitly.

Comment: StoryTeller - for each API method I want to use, adding a pure virtual function to `MasterClassBC` and in the template calling `TBase::one()` seems to work. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Danny - Yeah that's what I mean. There's a name for it, "Adapter" or "Bridge", I can't recall exactly.

Comment: StoryTeller, thanks.  Your suggestion works well -- as long as the signatures are exactly the same between `APIClass1` and `APIClass2`.  Now I find that a few have different signatures.  See the edit above.  How to handle that?

Comment: Have you looked into partial template specialization?  Specify a 'master' version of a method than contains all necessary parameters and use specialization to forward to the correct version?

Comment: James, I just read up on partial template specialization and I'm not sure how to do that in this case.  `APIClass1` and `APIClass2` cannot be modified.  Any suggestion on how to 'forward' to the correct version?